# Binding with private Dependency Property works differently as compared to private CLR property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties, dependency-properties

I have a window with DataContext set to itself with this simple XAML layout -

```
<StackPanel>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameCLR}"/>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameDP}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and in code behind i have two properties `NameCLR - CLR property` and `NameDP - Dependency Property`.

```
    private string NameCLR
    {
        get { return "CLRProperty"; }
    }

    private string NameDP
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameDPProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameDPProperty, value); }
    }

    private static readonly DependencyProperty NameDPProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("NameDP", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow),
                                        new UIPropertyMetadata("DPProperty"));
```

Since code-behind is a partial class definition and partial is XAML. So, i was assuming that private property should be visible to XAML. But to my amazement CLR and DP behaves differently.

> Private Dependency property is accessible but private CLR property
>   isn't.

I got the output as -

```
DPProperty
```

instead of

```
CLRProperty
DPProperty
```

Can someone let me know about this different behaviour in DP and CLR property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bound property is accessed by the Binding, not by the declaring class. A private CLR property like `NameCLR` is inaccessible, hence the Binding won't work.

However, when resolving the property path `NameDP` the Binding apparently bypasses the CLR wrapper for that property and directly accesses the underlying dependency property, which was registered with the dependency property system by calling `DependencyProperty.Register`. It is not relevant whether you have assigned the returned DependencyProperty reference to a private or public static field in your class. The dependency property was registered for your class, hence it can be looked up.

From the link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) -

> Dependency properties on a given type are accessible as a storage
>   table through the property system, the WPF implementation of its XAML
>   processor uses this table and infers that any given property ABC can
>   be more efficiently set by calling SetValue on the containing
>   DependencyObject derived type, using the dependency property
>   identifier ABCProperty.

Comment: This is important to know for another reason; since the Binding system uses the dependency property directly, it will never call the getter and setter for the 'friendly wrapper' standard property exposed on the class.  It's a very common mistake to put some special logic in the setter for this wrapper property, only to discover that it's not being called when the value is updated by the Binding system.

Comment: @Clemens - `CLR property cannot be accessed because property lookup is done by binding` - Fair enough. But as mentioned binding will access underlying static DP property identifier which i have marked private. So, how it will be accessed?

Comment: @RohitVats No, the binding will not access your `private static` field. It will get the property value directly from the dependency property system. Directly accessing the static field wouldn't work anyway, as it is static and thus not associated to any instance of your class.

Comment: Ok got it. +1. Can you please let me know that how dependency property system works internally to get instance property of class?

Comment: @DanBryant Could you perhaps provide any reference for what you say which explicitly mentions bindings? The explanations in [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) etc. all refer to directly setting properties in XAML, at least to my understanding.

Comment: @RohitVats I guess it simply calls `DependencyObject.GetValue`.

Comment: From the link you mentioned in comment above, i got this - `dependency properties on a given type are accessible as a storage table through the property system, the WPF implementation of its XAML processor uses this table and infers that any given property ABC can be more efficiently set by calling SetValue on the containing DependencyObject derived type, using the dependency property identifier ABCProperty.` which slights clear picture to me that a table is maintained internally on class type and XAML processor lookup to it for resolving.

Comment: I have updated your answer with that quote from a link and accepted. Thanks a lot for the link. :)

Comment: I'd still be very interested in a link to some MDSN documentation that explicitly mentions bindings, not the "XAML processor" they talk about here. Property path resolution in a binding is something different than XAML processing.